# Should I put index.js in every component in react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well, I've read
https://medium.com/bootstart/you-should-be-using-folder-components-b30b7d165c39
article where author describes `index.js` as a cure and there is also comment in that article in which another person tells that it is redundant to make `index.js` in every component.

But! There are many repositories over github such

- https://github.com/discountry/react/tree/master/src/components
- https://github.com/geist-org/react/tree/master/components
- https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/tree/master/src/components

where they use `index.js` in every single component.

So, do we have to use them? Is it really necessary?

Comment: Yes, it makes life easier when you do import.

Comment: this is completely opinon based

Comment: This question is extremely subjective and is likely to be closed. I'd think about a way to phrase it that doesn't just depend on anecdotal evidence, or even purely opinion.

Comment: Since your putting the component file into a folder, why not just name the file `index.js` instead of creating an additional file?

Answer (score 1):

> ...it is redundant to make index.js in every component

Creating index.js helps in importing that component in different components/containers directly using:

```
import LayoutHeader from '../LayoutHeader';
```

instead of (without index.js):

```
import LayoutHeader from '../LayoutHeader/LayoutHeader';
```

Creating `index.js` in `/` for a single import element for an entire component feels redundant, but can be helpful when you want to have multiple elements in a single component (Not a very modular approach). Then you can use a single index file to export all the elements of the component.

Both practices are valid, and usually depends on programmer.